# Best way to visulaize what sites are taking up stats? (i have a dedicated server)

Tags: unix, bandwidth

i have a dedicated server with lots of domains hosted. what is the best way to see how much bandwidth etc each is using?

Answer (score 1):

Your host should be able to split the logs out into separate logs per domain. Then you can run webstats utility on each.